# Codeigniter - anchor uri segment - creating a template file to load in dynamic data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am currently making a static site into a dynamic one and have been using codeigniter to do this without any problem .. until now.

The problem I have is that I want to have one view (webpage) that acts as a template file and pulls in dynamic data from my database depending on what link was clicked.

In the website there is a **overview jobs page** where it has a sidebar that lists all current vacancies. What I want is when a user clicks on one of these links it will load the template file and pull in all the data (job description, job title etc) that relates to that job.

I don't think that I am to far away from achieving this but I am having some problems.

First I have created a function in the controller(**site**) which loads a model and function (**getJobInfo**) that gets the job title from the database (depending on the location). Then it gets the header, nav,  content and pulls of of it into the view named "**jobs**".

In the jobs overview page I have used a foreach statement to load in the job title which will be used as the link to click on, here it will then load the template file with all the related data. In this foreach statement I have used a codeigniter anchor statement to load a new function (**job position**) back in the controller, this will be used to display and get all of the job specific information. I have also passed in the jobs listing id as the third segment of the anchor which will be used by a new model in the new site controller function (**job position**) where it will only show the related information to that id (where query).

If that makes no sence hopfully this will clarify.

**Controller - job overview function**

```
public function jobs(){
$this->load->model("get_db");
$data['jobheader'] = $this->get_db->getJobHeader('3');
$data['joblocationlisting'] = $this->get_db->getJobLocationListing('manchester');
$data['header'] = $this->get_db->getHeaders('3');
$data['content'] = $this->get_db->getContent('2');
$this->load->view("header", $data);
$this->load->view("nav");
$this->load->view("jobs", $data);
}
```

**Model - get job title**

```
public function getJobLocationListing($job_location){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT job_location, job_listing_id, job_title 
FROM job_location INNER JOIN job_listing ON job_location.job_location_id =
job_listing.job_location_id WHERE job_location = '$job_location'" );
return $query->result();
}
```

**View - jobs**

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($joblocationlisting as $row)
{ 
   $title = $row->job_title;
?>
<li>
<?php
   echo anchor("site/jobPosition/$row->job_listing_id", $title);
?>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

**Controller - job position function**

```
public function jobPosition(){
$this->load->model("get_db");
$data['jobposition'] = $this->get_db->getJobInfo();
$this->load->view("header", $data);
$this->load->view("nav");
this->load->view("jobTemplate", $data);
}
```

**Model - get job info**

```
public function getJobInfo(){
$query = $this->db->where('job_listing_id', $this->uri->segment(3));
$this->db->get('job_listing');
return $query->result();
}
```

**View - job position - template**

```
<?php foreach($jobposition as $row)
{ 
  $jobtitle = $row->job_title;
  $jobdescription = $row->job_description;
}
?>

 h1><?php echo $jobtitle; ?></h1>
 <p><?php echo $jobdescription; ?></p>
```

The problem I have is that the anchor tag is loading the function - site/jobPosition(and the id number)   e.g site/jobPosition/1. What I want is to load for the anchor to run the function site/jobPosition but it to pass the job_listing_id into the function which will then pass it to the **getJobInfo** model. Here it will which will get the data depending on that id cliked and then it will return it back to the **jobPosition** function for it to be displayed into the **jobTemplate** view.

Am I far away from doing this because I think I'm pretty close as have followed this tutorial video - http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-5-crud/ - and it works for him with deleted data instead of selecting and displaying it.
Thanks (sorry for the massive post).

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, I franky had a bit of difficulties understanding the problem, so bear with me if I'm wrong:

So far you're fetching the job_listing_id using the uri segment

```
$query = $this->db->where('job_listing_id', $this->uri->segment(3));
```

You're already creating (with the anchor() method) the correct url, so why then in your controller you ignore the argument passed, and rely on the uri segment to fetch it? Why not doing:

```
   public function jobPosition($job_listing_id){
    $this->load->model("get_db");
    $data['jobposition'] = $this->get_db->getJobInfo($job_listing_id);
    $this->load->view("header", $data);
    $this->load->view("nav");
    this->load->view("jobTemplate", $data);
    }
```

Model - get job info

```
public function getJobInfo($job_listing_id){
$query = $this->db->where('job_listing_id', $job_listing_id);
$this->db->get('job_listing');
return $query->result();
}
```

When you pass additional segments in the url they're automatically passed down to the controller method as arguments, so a url like yours,

```
  echo anchor("site/jobPosition/$row->job_listing_id", $title);
```

will automatically hand the jobPosition() controller an argument, which is likely what you want.

**EDIT**

Maybe I get it. Try changing routes:

```
// Put this after the default routes:
$route['jobPosition/(:num)'] = "jobPosition/jobPosition/$1";
```

Now make sure your controller jobposition.php has the class jobPosition and the method jobPosition($job_listing_id) I posted up here. I used "jobPosition" for the method name for simplicity, change it accordingly to what you prefer: the router will pick up the URL that matches your rule (`$route['jobPosition/(:num)']`) and forward the request to any controller/method/argument you define

Comment: I see that makes sence, thanks I have edited the code to match that . I am getting ok with codeigniter but still unfamiliar with things like this but I see how it works. However the when a user clicks on a link the jobPosition function is not run as I believe it is looking for a function called jobPostion/1 which you obviusly cannot put as a controller name. It might make more sence if I gave you the URL for the project I am working on -
http://digitalblue.im/Sandbox-Digital-Blue/site/jobs
- if you click on a job listing link then it loads a blank page.

Comment: Oh, maybe I understood, check my edit. I believe your problem is related to routing

Comment: Ok thanks, Do I need to create a new controller for this function/method like you are describing or can I change (jobPosition/jobPosition/$1) to the controller I am using for every function which is called "site". Therefore wouldn't it read - (site/jobPosition/$1) - is that possible is a new controller needed ?

Comment: I have tried it with both jobPosition/jobPosition/$1 where i changed the anchor tag to link to the new controller and I get error message. I also tried it by changing it to site/jobPosition/$1 and nothing happens. Any ideas as it seems so close.

Comment: I have fixed the problem. In the get job info function the query for selecting and returning the data was wrong. Instead of using :

$query = $this->db->where('job_listing_id', $this->uri->segment(3));
$this->db->get('job_listing');

It should have been :

$query = $this->db->get_where('job_listing',array('job_listing_id' => $job_listing_id));
return $query->result();

hope this helps with other peoples problems. Thanks for the help anyway it was useful.